# How to make the biblatex inline reference clickable to online URL?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I doing beamer presentation and I don't want to list my references at the end. I the clicking behaviour to navigate to the web URL of specific reference, not to the location of the  bibliography. So, I need to use \cite{} or \textcite{}, then when I click on the inline reference, I navigate to URL using web browser.

Is that possible?

Comment: i'm sure it's possible (don't know biblatex well enough to answer, sorry) but in a presentation you presumably don't have many \cite you could simply change them all to \href it would only be a couple of minutes editing?

Comment: Actually, I works well if I wrapped \cite command with \href ! thank you for that suggestions. However, I find it difficult to keep copying the links to the href. If there is a solution to automatically retrieve link from bibtex file to pass it to href would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard styles use the field format `bibhyperref` to typeset the citation link. We can redefine this format to link to the `url` instead of the bibliography entry.

The example below enables links via the `doi` and `url` fields.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {\@firstofone}
       {\href{\thefield{url}}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}}%
  {#1}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ctan,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked citations (not actually visible in the screenshot)]

Comment: Excellent Snippet!